# Appending parameters from a list in a for loop

Tags: python, json

I have a list with several data, ['a','b','c'...]

The goal here is to read all the items in the list and access to a json file to retrieve that information.

The json i have is as follows

```
{
"a": {  
"b": { 
"c": { .... }
}
} }
```

So, the final sentence to execute is

```
code.get(list[0]).get(list[1]).get(list[2]...get(list[n]
```

Is there any way i can do a for loop based on the length of the list to do this?

Something like, for any item in the list, append a ..get(list[i]) to my sentence

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the key list and go down into the `code` dict:

```
keys =  ['a','b','c']
current_level = code # Top level
for key in keys:
    current_level = current_level.get(key) # Descent next level
print current_level # Value of the 'c' dict
```